# Cart clear after 2 hours in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, magento2.4.5

As a guest I add products in the cart at 10am and when I check the cart back at 12am the cart is empty.

i have set a time approx 1 year but still it's not working .
We have no cron job for this .
I checked the log files too and there are no errors related to this .
i test it with 5 min its working fine but if i set time more then 2 hours its not working
i check the database there are time is set correct which we set in our admin

Could anyone suggest the solution to fix this issue so that we can move further